# Creating Custom Modules tutorial doesn't work - help!

Tags: theming, 8, routes

I'm trying to teach myself how to create a custom module using Drupal 8, and followed the instructions on their website at this [Drupal.org documentation page](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules)

I created the folders, hello_world.info.yml, hello_world.routing.yml and HelloController.php pages and have been over them time and time again looking for typos, but can't find any.

I've got to the step to add [add a routing file](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/add-a-routing-file).  The module appears in the Extend area, but when I enable it and click Install, after a short pause I get the error "The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later."

When I go back to thet Extend, the module is ticked and I presume installed.

However when I then try to display it using the URL "/hello", I get a "Page Not Found".  Not only that, but every time I try to clear the cache, there is a delay and I get the same "Website encountered..." error again.  I can only clear the cache by uninstalling the module.

I've included the content of the three files below:

**/modules/hello_world/hello_world.info.yml**

```
name: Hello world Module
description: Creates a page showing "Hello world"
package: Custom
type: module
core: 8.x
```

**/modules/hello_world/hello_world.routing.yml**

```
hello_world.content:
  path: '/hello'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\hello_world\Controller\HelloController::content'
    _title: 'Hello world'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

**/modules/hello_world/src/Controller/HelloController.php**

```
<?php
    namespace Drupal\hello_world\Controller;

    use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;

    class HelloController extendes ControllerBase {

        public function content() {
            return array(
                '#type' => 'markup',
                '#markup' => $this->t('Hello World'),
            );
        }
    }
```

Does anyone have any suggestions what might be wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class HelloController extendes ControllerBase {
```

You spelled extends incorrectly.

Comment: IDEs to the rescue. Not that I haven't done this before...

Comment: @Kevin, j/w which one do you use?

Comment: PHPStorm and maybe eventually VSCode if they ever fix the mysterious CPU usage spike bug and get better PHP support.

Comment: Thanks!  Developers tunnel vision, I'd checked and rechecked it for spacing, tab alignment, everything except a simple spelling error. I use Sublime for the colour coding as well and never spotted it!  Works perfectly, many thanks. Now I'll just find a dark corner and hide until the embarrassment wears off.  Then I'll take a look at PHPStorm.

Thanks again :)